# Problema para apk ionic: "Platform android already added."

Tags: ionic, cordova, ionic2

Ya tengo mi proyecto Ionic listo y funciona sin errores. Al ejecutar el comando:

```
cordova platform add android
```

sale este código en el terminal de Ubuntu:

> ```
> Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^6.2.3
> Error: Platform android already added.
> ```

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: ya tienes puesto android, no necesitas volver a añadirlo

Comment: ya tienes la plataforma android agregada en tu proyecto.

Comment: como se haria eso?

Answer (score -1):

debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```